# Usage of runOnlyAtExecutionRoot inside pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi module pom and I want to assembly a jar-with-dependencies for the parent. But I don't need to build the assembly for every module, they don't event have assembly descriptors. So I'm using the runOnlyAtExecutionRoot parameter of the maven-assembly-plugin with limited success:

1. If I enter the parameter through commandline, it works: skips assembling the modules and the parent project assembly is generated:
   `mvn compile assembly:single -DrunOnlyAtExecutionRoot=true`
2. It I enter the parameter into the parent POM, it is ignored:
   `mvn compile assembly:single`
   In the pom.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.orgPOM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>my.company</groupId>
       <artifactId>thisApp</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>pom</packaging>
       <name>thisApp Parent Project</name>

       <modules>
           <module>my.company.thisApp.main</module>
           <module>my.company.library-1</module>
           <module>my.company.library-1.library-1-1</module>
           <module>my.company.library-1.library-1-2</module>
           <module>my.company.library-2</module>
           <module>my.company.library-3</module>
           <module>my.company.library-3.library-3-1</module>
       </modules>

       <build>
           <pluginManagement>
               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                       <configuration>
                           <source>1.8</source>
                           <target>1.8</target>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>3.0.0</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>true</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
                           <descriptorRefs>
                               <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                           </descriptorRefs>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </pluginManagement>
       </build>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>my.company.thisApp</groupId>
               <artifactId>main</artifactId>
               <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </project>
   ```

The second way isn't working, it tries to assembly each of the modules and it fails because 'no assembly descriptors found' for them.

What's the right way to specify the parameter runOnlyAtExecutionRoot in the POM? I've also tried to put it into an 'execution' without success.

Answer (score 1):

It fails, because the descriptor reference "jar-with-dependencies" can not be assembled for a project with packaging POM (like a parent project). When running:

```
mvn clean package assembly:single
```

I got following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0:single (default-cli) on project my-parent: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: You must set at least one file.
```

It says that there must be at least one file, meaning at least on file must be added to the assembly. Since there is no packaged jar, it can not be done.

A solution is the usage of an assembly descriptor in the parent POM, which adds packaged jars and libraries of jar modules (see [copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)) or an uber jar (see [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)).

An example: Create a descriptor file in the parent project under src/main/assembly/ and reference it under "descriptors" in the plugin configuration. My descriptor is called "my-descriptor.xml"

```
<configuration>
  <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>true</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
  <descriptors>
    <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/my-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
  </descriptors>
</configuration>
```

The descriptor adds the wished files to a distribution zip file. My descriptor picks up the packaged jar of the module "my-service" and looks like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>my-service/target/my-service-${project.version}.jar</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: You are right when your say that a project with packaging pom has no file to add to the assembly, but that fact dissapears as soon as you declare a dependency on any of its modules: then it has to add at least that module's files, so the error "You must set at least one file" dissapears. I've modified the question to show the full pom.

Comment: Is the descriptor reference "jar-with-dependencies" working for you, when you add the dependency?

Comment: Yes, the descriptor reference "jar-with-dependencies" works for the parent pom when it has something to add (the dependency in this case). The problem is with the parameter runOnlyAtExecutionRoot, which is only honored if entered through command line.